# nextjs /home/grafeno30/src/NextJS/file-based-routing/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js:315

Tags: next.js

I would like to create my first project in NextJS. I follow this steps:

npx create-next-app@latest

npm run dev

But I get the following error:

```
grafeno30@linuxHome:~/src/NextJS/file-based-routing/my-app$ npm run dev
> my-app@0.1.0 dev
> next dev
/home/grafeno30/src/NextJS/file-based-routing/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js:315
            showAll: args["--show-all"] ?? false,
                                         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.dev (/home/grafeno30/src/NextJS/file-based-routing/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/lib/commands.js:10:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/grafeno30/src/NextJS/file-based-routing/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:141:28)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
grafeno30@linuxHome:~/src/NextJS/file-based-routing/my-app$ rm -rf node_modules
grafeno30@linuxHome:~/src/NextJS/file-based-routing/my-app$ npm install
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'eslint-import-resolver-typescript@3.5.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^14.18.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'next@13.0.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.6.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'synckit@0.8.4',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^14.18.0 || >=16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
added 251 packages, and audited 252 packages in 6s
86 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
found 0 vulnerabilities
grafeno30@linuxHome:~/src/NextJS/file-based-routing/my-app$ npm run dev
> my-app@0.1.0 dev
> next dev
/home/grafeno30/src/NextJS/file-based-routing/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js:315
            showAll: args["--show-all"] ?? false,
                                         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.dev (/home/grafeno30/src/NextJS/file-based-routing/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/lib/commands.js:10:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/grafeno30/src/NextJS/file-based-routing/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:141:28)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)*
```

I tried delete node_modules folder and after execute "npm install". But it still giving me the same error

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to upgrade node version, im using the latest 19.2.0 and it's work fine